# How to put jsp in ROOT folder of tomcat so that the jsp is picked by all web apps

Tags: java, tomcat

I have multiple web applications defined in my tomcat. In case of any exception, I want to throw one jsp (done using SimpleMappingExceptionResolver tag of spring). When I put the jsps in the web-inf folder of the web applications, it works fine which is obvious.
But I want to put this jsp at a common place in tomcat such as ROOT library. But if I do this, tomcat is not able to find my jsp. Can somebody tell me if any changes in web.xml is required to make this happen or I should put this jsp somewhere else.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8748134/784540

Comment: Hi Rafael, I had already gone through this link but this is not what I wanted. I have to put one jsp in a common location and all the web application should be able to access this jsp, when an exception comes.

Comment: Register tomcat error page in `CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml`. Use `<error-page>` tag for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by 'picked up' or 'access'? You can put a jsp file on the tomcat ROOT application, and do a 302 redirect into it everytime you encounter exception.

For example place you all-apps generic exception page on webapps/ROOT/generic_exception.jsp, then on each of your apps, add this to the web.xml

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/myapp_error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

That should redirect request into myapp_error.jsp (inside myapp) if any uncaught exception surfaces. Then inside myapp_error.jsp, just perform html meta redirect to /generic_exception.jsp

However the drawback of this approach is you are redirected into different web-app, it's difficult / require extra work if you want to pass session attributes

Comment: Thanks gerry. But this won't work in my case. I have used below spring feature to get the jsp name when 
GenericException is thrown.
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="com.example.exceptions.GenericException">
                    genericException
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
So I have to somehow put this genericException.jsp in ROOT folder so that tomcat renders this page on GenericException

Comment: You can put a 302 redirect on your genericException.jsp to get into the ROOT exception handler, except you can't pass session attributes